# Creating a trigger on delete operation

Tags: plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger to show an error message when trying to delete a stock name from a table if the quantity is available. Can someone explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WHEN` clause in a trigger so it only fires on the condition. In the example the error is thrown if quantity is equal or higher than 100

```
koen>create table stocks (id number, name varchar2(100), qty number);

Table STOCKS created.

koen>insert into stocks(id, name, qty) values (1,'ORCL',100);

1 row inserted.

koen>insert into stocks(id, name, qty) values (1,'AMZN',20);

1 row inserted.

koen>create or replace trigger stocks_bd
  2    before delete
  3    on stocks
  4    for each row
  5    WHEN (old.qty >= 100 )
  6  begin
  7  raise_application_error(
  8      -20001, 
  9      'Quantity too high');
 10  end;
 11* /

Trigger STOCKS_BD compiled

koen>delete from stocks where name = 'AMZN';

1 row deleted.

koen>delete from stocks where name = 'ORCL';

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
delete from stocks where name = 'ORCL'
Error report -
ORA-20001: Quantity too high
ORA-06512: at "ACDC.STOCKS_BD", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ACDC.STOCKS_BD'

koen>
```